# How to hide Command prompt in Microsoft Edge SeleniumTools

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, selenium, microsoft-edge

Hi i'm using selenium to open edge(Chromium) then navigate to a URL. written in c# windowsform application

Here is the code

```
IWebDriver edgeDriver;

                    var options = new EdgeOptions();
                    options.UseChromium = true;

                     edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(options);
                    edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@Config.SpcUrl);
```

it is working fine

what i have try is this to hide the command prompt

```
IWebDriver edgeDriver;
     var chromeDriverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                        chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                        var options = new EdgeOptions();
                        options.UseChromium = true;

                         edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(chromeDriverService ,options);
                        edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@Config.SpcUrl);
```

but it gives me an error of

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools.dll

Additional information: options.UseChromium must be set to false when using an Edge Legacy driver service.
```

What i'm doing wrong or i'm missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solve i use `CreateChromiumService` insted of `EdgeOptions`

so the final code looks like this

```
 var chromeDriverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateChromiumService();
                    chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                    var options = new EdgeOptions();
                    options.UseChromium = true;

                    edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
                    edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@Config.SpcUrl);
```

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, or when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.^_^